# Can I compare different rows in the same MySQL table (SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to compare different rows in the same MySQL table? I want to count how many users have changed their names.

Here is roughly what I got in the MySQL log table...

```
id   userid    name
1    1         Joe
2    1         Joe
3    1         Joe
4    2         Fiona
5    3         Mark
6    3         Marcel
7    3         Marcel
8    4         Mary
9    4         Marie
```

You can see that Joe's name has not changed even though he is in the log table 3 times. "Mark" was changed to "Marcel" and "Mary" was changed to "Marie". So if this was the whole of the table, I want to know that 2 people have changed their names (out of four).

```
SELECT userid, GROUP_CONCAT(name) FROM tablename GROUP BY userid ORDER BY userid  DESC
```

I can examine the output with a scripting language (PHP), I'm just wondering if there is something I can do in SQL that would be neater and only give me the names that are changed.

I'm not sure if this is possible. Haven't found a solution to this yet, if it's a duplicate please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Can you also show the `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` so we know indexes as well and information how large this log table is `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a `HAVING` clause?

```
SELECT userid
FROM tablename
GROUP BY userid
HAVING MIN(name) <> MAX(name)
ORDER BY userid DESC;
```

If you want the names without duplicates:

```
SELECT userid, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT name)
FROM tablename
GROUP BY userid
HAVING MIN(name) <> MAX(name)
ORDER BY userid DESC;
```